# How to log SQL queries, their parameters and results with Log4jdbc in Spring Boot projects?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, logging, spring-data-jpa

To view SQL queries sent to DB we usually use `showSql` parameter:

```
spring.jpa.showSql=true
```

It allows us to see the statement body but not its parameters:

```
insert into master (id, version, name) values (null, ?, ?)
```

And especially we don't see a result of the query.

Is there a way to see SQL statement, its parameters and result in the application log?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## JDBC logging

With **[log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/candrews/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter)** we can easily **log all JDBC statements**, their parameters and results in Spring Boot/Spring Data JPA projects.

For example, when we perform some JPQL query in our application:

```
select u from User u where u.name = 'john'
```

then we see the following SQL query with its parameter in the application log:

```
select ... from users users0_ where users0_.name='john'
```

And its result in the table form:

```
|---|---------|
|id |name     |
|---|---------|
|1  |john     |
|---|---------|
```

To use this starter we have to add its dependency to our project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.integralblue</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and add these parameters to `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.jdbc.resultsettable=info
logging.level.jdbc.sqltiming=info
logging.level.jdbc.sqlonly=fatal
logging.level.jdbc.audit=fatal
logging.level.jdbc.resultset=fatal
logging.level.jdbc.connection=fatal
```

Additionally, we can add these **log4jdbc** parameters to get the output in one line:

```
log4jdbc.dump.sql.addsemicolon=true
log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength=0
log4jdbc.trim.sql.extrablanklines=false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have a question, I want to save these logs on a table in my data base . How can I do that ??