# Angular 4 update nested field

Tags: angular, rest, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

Having trouble with updating my model using `@angular/http method http.put()`.

The issue is that I just can't update Position at all. I can successfully update any other field and can set any Position when creating with POST.

My angular version is "^4.3.3"

In java my model looks like

```
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String name;

    String email;

    String phone;

    Date birthDay;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "position_id")
    Position position;
}
```

Projection:

```
public interface EmployeeProjection {

    Long getId();

    String getName();

    String getEmail();

    String getPhone();

    Date getBirthDay();

    @Value("#{target.position.name}")
    String getPosition();
}
```

And Position class:

```
public class Position {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

In angular template Position:

```
<md-select mdInput placeholder="Position"
           [(ngModel)]="newEmployee.position">
  <md-option *ngFor="let position of positions | async" [value]="position.name">{{ position.name }}
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

My update method in component:

```
update() {
    let positionName = this.employee.position;
    this.positionService.findByName(positionName).subscribe(position => {
      this.employee.position = position._links.self.href;
      this.employeeService.update(this.employee);
      this.employee.position = positionName;
      this.employeeService.localStorageService.set('employee', this.employee);
    });
  }
```

And in service:

```
update(employee: Employee) {
    this.http.put(employee._links.self.href, employee)
      .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.getAll();
      });
    return employee;
  }
```

In chrome Request:

```
{
  "name": "Nikolai Morgan",
  "id": 1,
  "position": "http://localhost:9080/api/positions/5",
  "birthDay": "1986-07-01",
  "email": "NikolaiMorgan@gmail.com",
  "phone": "+380840713229",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1"
    },
    "employee": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1{?projection}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "position": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1/position"
    }
  }
}
```

But response and preview not contain field Position:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Nikolai Morgan",
  "email" : "NikolaiMorgan@gmail.com",
  "phone" : "+380840713229",
  "birthDay" : "1986-07-01",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1"
    },
    "employee" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "position" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1/position"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So 'What is the question?', Hamlet? ;)

Comment: how to update value of nested field in model?

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update entity that has reference to another one, in Spring Data REST you have to use a link to this entity. For example:

```java
@Entity
class Employee {
    //...

    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    Position position;   

    //...
}

@Entity
class Position {
    //...

    String name;

    //...
}

interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
interface PositionRepo extends JpaRepository<Position, Long> {}
```

First we add a position:

`POST http://localhost:9080/api/positions`

```json
{
    "name": "position1"
}
```

And get a response like this:

```json
{
    "name": "position1",
    "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/positions/1"
        },
        "position" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/positions/1"
        }
    }
}
```

Then add an employee:

`POST http://localhost:9080/api/employees`

```json
{
    "name": "employee1",
    "employee": "http://localhost:9080/api/positions/1"
}
```

Then get a response:

```json
{
  "name" : "employee1",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1"
    },
    "employee" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1",
    },
    "position" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1/position"
    }
  }
}
```

So if we need to update position we create a new one, then PUT the employee:

`PUT http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1`

```json
{
    "name": "employee1", 
    "position": "http://localhost:9080/api/positions/2"
}
```

Or even PATCH it:

`PATCH http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1`

```json
{
    "position": "http://localhost:9080/api/positions/2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, i picked variant with PATCH. I'd also would be grateful if you clearify how to update with PUT using existing position and employee

Comment: In my code you can see i setted link for position too, but that didn't fire. I want to understand where is my mistake

Comment: Что ты имеешь в виду под "didn't fire"? В Response, который ты привел, ссылка на `position` присутствует: `http://localhost:9080/api/employees/1/position`. Или новая позиция в БД не сохраняется? Или что?..

Comment: Да, обновляются все поля, кроме позиции, она просто игнорится, хотя в сеттер она приходит, но в репозитории при сохранении уже старое значение

Comment: Подключи [логировнаие](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45346905) - посмотри, какие реально запросы идут в базу. И еще, не работает только PUT или PATCH тоже?..

Comment: не работает только PUT, если изменять только позицию, то в бд сохранение не идет так как в SimpleJpaRepository#save приходит модель со старым значением, тогда как в сеттер приходит новое

Comment: @MolecularMan Switch to version 1.4.3 of Spring Boot. It seems that there is a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1100) in version 1.5.x. ((