# Why is a simple Hibernate findOne() by primary key taking so long?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I'm splitting this off from [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641420/why-is-hibernates-select-before-save-taking-so-long) to eliminate the 'select before save' confusion. In this example, I'm trying to do a simple findOne() by primary key. This is against an existing sqlserver db, with the latest versions of spring boot and spring data.

I have the logging set so I can see the sql that hibernate has generated. In this example, according to the logging timing, this query takes about 4 seconds. This is querying with a primary key. When I run the sql that hibernate generated in a db tool like dbvisualizer, it returns in sub-second, as I would expect.

I increased the hibernate packaging logging to TRACE level, to try to see where the delay is, and found the following, before and after the 4 second delay:

```
2017-08-14 09:51:35.345 DEBUG 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select customer0_.customer_id as customer1_4_0_, customer0_.first_name as first_na2_4_0_, customer0_.last_name as last_nam3_4_0_ from xbr_customer_tab customer0_ where customer0_.customer_id=?
Hibernate: select customer0_.customer_id as customer1_4_0_, customer0_.first_name as first_na2_4_0_, customer0_.last_name as last_nam3_4_0_ from xbr_customer_tab customer0_ where customer0_.customer_id=?
2017-08-14 09:51:35.470 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Registering statement [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy[Proxy=25287222; Query=select customer0_.customer_id as customer1_4_0_, customer0_.first_name as first_na2_4_0_, customer0_.last_name as last_nam3_4_0_ from xbr_customer_tab customer0_ where customer0_.customer_id=?; Delegate=SQLServerPreparedStatement:6]]
2017-08-14 09:51:35.471 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Registering last query statement [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy[Proxy=25287222; Query=select customer0_.customer_id as customer1_4_0_, customer0_.first_name as first_na2_4_0_, customer0_.last_name as last_nam3_4_0_ from xbr_customer_tab customer0_ where customer0_.customer_id=?; Delegate=SQLServerPreparedStatement:6]]
2017-08-14 09:51:35.479 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [40666316]
2017-08-14 09:51:35.488 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.l.p.e.i.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader  : Bound [2] parameters total
2017-08-14 09:51:39.426 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Registering result set [SQLServerResultSet:6]
2017-08-14 09:51:39.434 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Processing result set
2017-08-14 09:51:39.434 DEBUG 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #0
2017-08-14 09:51:39.436 DEBUG 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] l.p.e.p.i.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl : On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified
2017-08-14 09:51:39.436 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] l.p.e.p.i.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl : hydrating entity state
```

I'm also wondering why it says 2 parameters bound, when there was only 1 in the sql.

Any ideas why this select is taking so long? Especially only in my spring app, and not in another client like dbvisualizer?

Here is the entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_customer_table")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String customer_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

    protected Customer() {}


    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.first_name = firstName;
        this.last_name = lastName;
    }

}
```

Here's the CustomerRepository

```
import com.....Customer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, String> {
}
```

and the code to look up a Customer, from a @Service class where CustomerRepository is @Autowired in:

```
Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(customerId);
```

Here is the generated sql:

```
select customer0_.customer_id as customer1_4_0_, customer0_.first_name as first_na2_4_0_, customer0_.last_name as last_nam3_4_0_ from my_customer_table customer0_ where customer0_.customer_id=?
```

Comment: is that all the logging?

Comment: ..and why is it binding as `VARCHAR`. Oh, your primary key is a varchar...that's an interesting choice.

Comment: primary key as varchar...yea like I said, pre-existing db...not sure who did it or when; we're writing a new app against this old db

Comment: @AmerQarabsa there's plenty more logging; how much do you want?

Comment: @user26270, could it be blocking occurs while the query is being run from the app code?  Try capturing rpc_starting and rpc_completed events using a SQL Server extended events trace. That will verify the server execution time.  The number of logical reads should be single-digits with a single-row select by the PK index.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by adding the following parameter to your connection string in the datasource.

```
sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
```

More detail : 
http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2014-05-01/java/fixing-slow-queries-running-sql-server-using-jpa-hibernate-and-jtds

Comment: wow, this parameter reduced our average query time by a factor of 10, thanks a lot!